# convert a function outputting string new line by new line to list

Tags: python, string, list

i have a function that is generating string elements using a for loop like this:

```
a
b
c
d
....
```

how can i convert my ouput to list like:

```
['a','b','c','d'...]
```

and so on..

the function is as follows:

```
def proper_lemmatize_sentence(sent, cond):
    tokens = word_tokenize(sent)
    tagged_tokens = pos_tag(tokens)
    for tagged_token in tagged_tokens:
        word = tagged_token[0]
        if cond:
            word_pos = tagged_token[1]
        else:
            word_pos = 'n'
        word_pos1 = get_wordnet_pos(word_pos)
        lemma = wnl.lemmatize(word, pos=word_pos1)
        print(lemma)
```

Comment: Define a list and append it with the value of `lemma`...

Comment: This gives me an output like : ['a'] ['b'] ['c'] ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the list **before** the loop; append to the list at the bottom of the loop; then return (or print) the list when the loop completes.

```
s = 'abcde'
def f(sequence):
    result = []
    for lemma in sequence:
        # do stuff
        result.append(lemma)
    return result

>>> print(f(s))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
text = text.split('\n')
```

Comment: This gives me an output like : 
['a']
['b']
['c'] 
and so on